# R Error in chol.default(A) krigeST from gstat package

Tags: r, variogram, spatio-temporal, kriging

I am working with an hourly dataset of air temperature, recorded at ~200 stations over a relatively small area. I chose a space-time variogram (e.g. sum-metric) to fit my data and am now trying to make predictions over my same stations in order to fill NA (missing value) gaps. When using the krigeST() function over daily aggregated data everything seems to go smooth but when I use it at the original hourly resolution I always get the following error:

Error in chol.default(A) the leading minor of order 68 is not positive definite

I googled it and found that it is related to a matrix not being completely positive-definite. However, I am not sure why this happens and was wondering if any of you know a way of fixing this (a workaround to avoid it).

Thanks!

---

In the empirical semivariogram model I specify initial values for the nugget and all other parameters. Then the optimal value is found by using the fit.variogram() function, which returns a value of 0 for the spatial, temporal, and joint spatio-temporal nugget. Do you think the problem comes from here? Why would a nugget of 0 cause that?

In general I am not trying to predict over a spatial grid, rather I am trying to predict on the same observations I use to develop the variogram. The reason why I need to do this, it to fill out several NA values in my spatiotemporal dataset. The way I do the estimation, after choosing the variogram model, is by cross-validation, hence I predict the spatio-temporal values at a given monitoring stations, using a certain number of neighbors from that station. Pretty much I am estimating the value on 1 station at a time, given a number of neighbors.

I tried to aggregate my values to daily max,min,mean temperature and I do not get that error anymore. In that case my estimated nuggets are not 0, aside from the joint space-time nugget.

Comment: The nugget is the measurement error, if the error is zero, then what you observed is the real value. In the cross validation, you delete your station from the observed one (adding  NA) and then you predict the process on that station, in this case you shouldn't have the error (is it?). Moreover, why you "use a certain number of neighboor" and not the entire observed process?

Comment: I get that error exactly when doing cross-validation to predict one station at a time given all others. I use a neighborhood to speed up the computing time but I get the same error when I use the entire observed process. I will try by manually changing the nugget from 0 to 1 and see. The only drawback is that by doing that, my space-time variogram fit gets worse (~3.2 RMSE) after adding a nugget manually.

Comment: Let me understand, when you do cross validation on station $s$ (for example), you use the model estimated with the other stations and $s$ (using its value or an NA)?

Comment: When I do cross-validation on station "s", I use the space-time variogram model fitted to the empirical variogram on all my observations (using their recorded values). As "newdata" in my ST kriging estimation, I specify station "s" (thus as if it was unknown) as the only one point on which to estimate the temperature. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Also, If I manually add a nugget variance, so that it is not equal to 0 anymore, I now get the following error in the krigeST() function:

Comment: Error in cbind(v0, X) : number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)

Comment: Station $s$ cannot be in the data used for model estimates and in the newdata. Moreover you cannot add a value of nugget at your wish. How you chose if it is 1 or 2 or 0.1. However, do you know this function:http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gstat/docs/krige.cv

Comment: @niandra82 I think the last error is because I forgot to use as( ,"STSDF") to my data in the krigeST() function. However, let me know if I answered your question...thanks for your help again!

Comment: @niandra82 station "s" is not in the data used to make prediction. That point is removed during CV and it is specified as newdata as prediction location. What I meant is that the variogram model was fitted to the empirical variogram. When calculating the empirical variogram and finding a theoretical variogram model, all available observations can be used.

Comment: @niandra82 as far as choosing a "nugget", why would I not be allowed to chose a value at wish? If I do so, the error may be bigger than using an automatic routine optim() to find best values that minimize errors but I still choose a variogram model with the parameters I specify.

Comment: if I let optim() find automatically the best values, both the space and time nuggets are set to 0, which causes the original error and perfect correlation like you said...

Comment: Another possible explanation is that you have some points that are really close, almost identical, if this is true than the covariance matrix is ill conditioned and the inversion can fail.

Comment: @niandra82 Yes, some points are really close, but still not more than, say, 300-400 meters over a 284 km^2 area. What would you do to prevent this "ill" conditioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use a nugget? If you don't, the prediction on the points used for the estimation of the model are just the observed points, then if you try to make prediction on then you will have a  correlation =1 and the matrix can be singular.